# JQuery toogleClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with my website. Basically I want to make a menu that drops down if you click on "menu". My nav looks like this:

```
    <nav class="col-12 col-m-12">
        <ul>
            <li id="menu"><a href="#">Meny</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Försörjning</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Kultur och rekreation</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Transport-lösningar</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Jobb och handel</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">IT-kommunikation</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Återvinning</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

When I click the list item at top I want it to set a class to "nav ul" called "menushow". I have tested to manually add the class through the inspector and it works. But my jQuery code doesn't want to work...

Here is my jQuery code:

```
//JQuery
$("#menu").click(function(){
    $("nav ul").toggleClass("menushow");
});
```

The problem is that it wont toggle the class to nav ul. Any help would be amazing!

Comment: That should work. You need to check for JS errors. Maybe you're not getting access to `$` where you put the jQuery code.

Comment: Can I see the errors in the google chrome inspector? Because I see none errors there...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
//JQuery
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menu").click(function(event){
        $("nav ul").toggleClass("menushow");
    });
});
```

I solved the problem!

Comment: because like i previously said, DOM was not ready when he was trying to assign the click function, by putting in the ready, he is sure of that

Comment: @lonut It gives nav ul the max-height of 62px. Witch means that all the other list elements will disappear. I do this so I can animate a transition.

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked for me... maybe double check your css.

```js
$("#menu").click(function(){
    $("nav ul").toggleClass("menushow");
});
```

```css
ul.menushow li a {
  color: green;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="col-12 col-m-12">
  <ul>
    <li id="menu"><a href="#">Meny</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Försörjning</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Kultur och rekreation</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Transport-lösningar</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Jobb och handel</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">IT-kommunikation</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Återvinning</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: actually it can be precised in CSS that menu doesnt hide, and i think it is better than adding a lot of classes, one is enough

Comment: Well. I tried adding the class to the nav ul in the google chrome inspector witch means it works... The thing that does not work is the JQuery wont assign the class to the nav ul element...

Comment: are all the DOM elements ready when you setup the click function? does it fire?

Comment: just add `:not:first-child` to the li in you CSS and all will be fine, definetly better than adding dozens of classes

Comment: just sayin that the class that is applied to the wole ul can specify that the first element is treated separately, it is just the same than your answer, but in CSS, not jQuery. And just one class is added instead of dozens, it makes way less DOM manipulations

Comment: @lonut no it wont. It will only change the max-height so you can only see the li button

Comment: sorry i'm a bit new in here, but you maybe shouldnt be so eager to defend your solution where we see it didnt answer the question. you just let the trailing `a` from the example in your fiddle. see this one :https://jsfiddle.net/5ak2eyyj/2/ i never stated that this was pure CSS, just less DOM manipulations